# How to make a 2D sprite follow mouse in Godot

Tags: godot

Please provide minimal code example of Sprite following the mouse in Godot. There are complex and big sample projects, but I didn't found nothing small and clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `Sprite` node in the scene, and attach the following script to it.

```
const SPEED = 500

func _process(delta):
    var vec = get_viewport().get_mouse_position() - self.position # getting the vector from self to the mouse
    vec = vec.normalized() * delta * SPEED # normalize it and multiply by time and speed
    position += vec # move by that vector
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in Godot 4.
Without `.normalized()`, the speed is relative to the distance between the sprite and the mouse cursor.

```
const SPEED = 200 # Set a higher speed to follow the mouse faster

func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = get_viewport().get_mouse_position() - self.position
    velocity = direction * delta * SPEED
    move_and_slide()
```